# How to position the -draw in imagemagick?

Tags: imagemagick

I am using imagemagick to draw a border on the top of an image.

THIS IS MY CODE:

```
convert source.jpg -stroke red -strokewidth 2 -fill transparent -draw \"roundrectangle 10,10 628,151 10,10\" source.jpg
```

This works fine but i need to be able to position the -draw where i want.

I tried to position the border like using `-geometry` like so:

```
convert source.jpg -stroke red -strokewidth 2 -fill transparent -geometry  +5+15 -draw \"roundrectangle 10,10 628,151 10,10\" source.jpg
```

But this does not position it where i want. I also tried using -`gravity` and that doesn't work either!

Could someone please advise on this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The position is specified by [the numbers following `roundrectangle`](http://php.net/manual/en/imagickdraw.roundrectangle.php).

Comment: -gravity and -geometry are probably not supported. I would position it by calculating the top left and bottom right co ordinates.

Comment: @unutbu, spot on...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bonzo is correct, you cannot use -geometry with -draw.

In ImageMagick with -draw you can also translate to where you want the center to be and then specify +- distances to the corners from the center placement.

Suppose you have a 100x100 size box you want draw and you want it centered at 250,250, then

```
convert input.jpg -stroke red -strokewidth 2 -fill transparent -draw "translate 250,250 roundrectangle -50,-50 50,50 10,10" output.png
```

That makes it easier to draw the same size boxes at different locations.

see
http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/draw/
http://www.imagemagick.org/script/magick-vector-graphics.php